# gradle: Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.sonarqube', version: '2.6.2']

Tags: sonarqube, gradlew

I'm trying to set up gradle 4.6 for sonarqube 7.0.

I added

```
"plugins {
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.6.2'
    }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'"
```

to build.gradle

Executing gradlew gives the following message.

```
* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.sonarqube', version: '2.6.2']
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not determine artifacts for org.sonarqube:org.sonarqube.gradle.plugin:2.6.2
      > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarqube/org.sonarqube.gradle.plugin/2.6.2/org.sonarqube.gradle.plug
in-2.6.2.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarqube/org.sonarqube.gradle.plugin/2.6.2/org.sonarqube.gradle.plugin-2.
6.2.jar'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderEx
ception: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get f
ull insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

D:\build\XX\XXX\trunk>gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-28 13:36:36 UTC
Revision:     8fa6ce7945b640e6168488e4417f9bb96e4ab46c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_162 (Oracle Corporation 25.162-b12)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

I assumed that would be problem because of the proxy in the company?

Therefore I added

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

to gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Any ideas what to check?

(At the end I want to setup gradlew with sonarqube and jacoco)

Thank you for the help

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/plugin-with-id-org-sonarqube-not-found/11588/12